# YouTube Updated API rel:0 deprecation alternative to custom coding

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

is there an OOB to the rel:0 api playerVars?

The documentation states it's deprecated, but no mention of replacement?
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018

Thanks!

Comment: Can an official Google/Youtube Developer please clarify what future state is?  If I am using this for a company intranet, I have firm requirements to remove these deprecated items - specifically the Top Bar (Title, Channel Logo, Share, etc) & most importantly the recommended videos at the end - they need suppressed.  Is there any specific Youtube Support Avenues I can take?

Answer (score 0):

They don't seem to have a plan to replace it. You could in theory use the JS api to figure out if the video has finished playing then swap out the elements.

Comment: "They don't seem to have a plan to replace it" - do you have references?